# PHP SOAP local server error

Tags: php, linux, soap

I'm struggling to get SOAP working on server locally. It's running on server and from my local PC I can use it, but when I'm using ssh to the server (both PC on linux) php gives me the error:

```
Error occurred: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://192.168.1.2:8080/WebServices/SetValues?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://192.168.1.2:8080/WebServices/SetValues?WSDL"
```

I tried Lynx locally from server and it's working fine. So problem is somewhere in PHP, SOAP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect
>   1

SE Linux was my problem!!! If anything happens with networking (even locally) blame SE Linux or firewall.

Comment: This post helped me second time :)_) I've installed my program on another server and forgot to configure SE Linux Policy properly, my own post saved my day!

Comment: wish I could claim this, but SE Linux is not even installed on my Ubuntu server. I access the Web Service from Windows server, my pc, etc, but not from Linux. I do not get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server binded to local (127.0.0.1)? Try to bind to 0.0.0.0

Comment: it's on 192.168.1.2 or 127.0.0.1 (localhost)

Comment: May be there is a Same Origin Policy violation?